# Ajax Modal Flickers When Opened Multiple Times

Tags: ajax, jquery, javascript

on my Wordpress site I add a button that when clicked calls a modal to open via ajax. When I click the button once on a fresh reload of the page it seems to work fine without any hiccups. If I close that modal then and click the button to open it again, without refreshing the page it will open, but flicker once and then stay opened. If I close it again and open it back up it flickers 3-4 times before staying open. And this continues with more flickers the more I click the button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// LAUNCH CALCULATOR/QUIZ MODAL
function qdLoadModal(){
    var options = {
            modal: true,
            height:300,
            width:500
        };

    $('#qdModalWindow').load('/wp-content/themes/gift/qdCalcModal.php');
    $('#qdModal').addClass('open');
    $('#qdModal').animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
    }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        //qdQuestionHeight();
    });


}

//Launch Quiz Modal
$('.calcLaunch').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    qdLoadModal();
});
});
```

That is the jQuery I am using to load in the modal file on button click. I can't figure out why the modal does the flickering thing when opened multiple times without reloading the page. If more information about my code is needed I can supply it, but really not sure what to do to fix it after a few hours of trying to troubleshoot it.

EDIT: I actually found a fix for this. I changed the click function to:

```
    $('.calcLaunch').one("click", function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    qdLoadModal();
    });
```

Changing the function to this then only runs it once on click removing the flicker.

Comment: WordPress is sort of incidental here. This is mostly a pure JavaScript question. You'll probably have more luck asking at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: even i am facing the same issue , but the above mentioned solution did not work for me, is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing children inside `#qdModalWindow` before attempting load new content inside it.

```
  $('#qdModalWindow').children().remove();
```